# R error in loading source script

Tags: r

I have a question about R software scripts. I'm new to R and have received a script from another user. There are two stages to this script: first, it loads a number of time-series libraries and, next, it loads some source code.

Here's the call:

```
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile); setwd(this.dir);options(warn=-1); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English");
library(twitteR) 
library(tm) 
library("tseries") 
library("zoo") 
library("xts") 
library("forecast")
library("quantmod")
library("wordcloud")
source("inc/config.r")
```

The error occurs on the "source("inc/config.r")" line. The error is:

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection

The call to config.r contains the following script:

```
tw_search_usr=c("CNNMoney","TheStreet", "FoxBusiness","SeekingAlpha", "WallstCS","themotleyfool",
"MarketWatch","CNBC","ReutersBiz","WSJ","YahooFinance",
"MicroFundy","chartly","MarketBeat","ReutersTV","BloombergTV","profitly","myrollingstocks",
"BloombergNews","Stockstobuy","tradespoon","stockr","stocktwits",
"FinancialBrand", "Option_Trading","EconomicTimes")

# Set up the list of stock symbols
stocksmbl<-c("AAPL","YHOO", "ORCL","MSFT")

# Set up max number of tweets which can be loaded for each user
n_tw=300;

# Set up time windows for analysis (days)
xts_window=100

min_freq_terms=5;
min_corr_assoc=0.03
filename_fts="loaded_feeds/fin_time_series.txt"
filename="loaded_feeds/users_tweets.txt"
rollmean_period=10
rollmean_period2=20
relative_freq_frsets=TRUE
```

My hunch is that the error is coming with the line:

```
filename_fts="loaded_feeds/fin_time_series.txt"
```

and may be due to the first line in the first script at the top which sets up "this.dir"

Any suggestions as to what's going wrong here?

Comment: It can't find the `"inc/config.r"` file. Make sure that file exists in whatever directory the working directory gets set to. Or change `"inc/config.r"` to an absolute file path

Comment: Using the absolute file path worked...Thanks!